# How much data can be stored using .data method?

Tags: javascript, jquery

How much data can be stored using $.data method in Jquery? Are there any pitfalls of using it?

I tried to get an answer for this very concrete question, however, I couldn't find any.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

I doubt there are any written limits. I think it depends on system (RAM) and browser settings, and by knowing how various machines can be novadays, it could be hard to state that $.data could store a certain amount of data.

Basically, what is $.data? It's a jquery method, that manages certain data that are identified by given variables. Basically, all ends up stored in simple (JSON perhaps?) JS variables, and how much a variable can hold - that is a different question.

My 2 cents.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Then I shouldn't be too worried to use it. Obviously, I wouldn't use it to store massive amounts of information.